# C# csharp аналог system() из с++

Tags: c#, .net, cmd

такой аналог system(char*) чтобы можно было делать так:

```
system("dir");system("ls");
system("mkdir papka & cd papka");
system("file.txt");
system("pause");
system("g++ main.cpp -std=c++14 -O2");
```

вообщем через cmd а не просто запуск того что есть в строке

Comment: я так понял тебе надо недокомпилятор сделать, делать на c++ компилируй c#

Comment: нет,просто задействовать функционал cmd из с#
чтобы каждый раз в консоли не набирать много разных cmd команд
и не хранить много батников

Comment: Ну сделайте обертку над `Process`, запускайте через него тихо консоль с нужной командой. Стандартно в c# нету вроде такого.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот один из вариантов решения консольной задачи.

Написал проект для примера в WPF, который полностью порабощает `cmd` :)

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Margin="5" PreviewKeyDown="TextBox1_PreviewKeyDown" />
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" IsReadOnly="True" FontFamily="Consolas" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Process cmdProcess = new Process();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            cmdProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd");
            cmdProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/K dir";
            cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            cmdProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += CmdProcess_OutputDataReceived;
            cmdProcess.ErrorDataReceived += CmdProcess_ErrorDataReceived;
            cmdProcess.Start();
            cmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
            cmdProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
        }

        private void CmdProcess_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                TextBox2.Text += e.Data + "\r\n";
                TextBox2.ScrollToEnd();
            });
        }

        private void CmdProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
            {
                TextBox2.Text += e.Data + "\r\n";
                TextBox2.ScrollToEnd();
            });
        }

        private void TextBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is TextBox textBox && e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                cmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(textBox.Text);
                textBox.Text = string.Empty;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В верхний текстбокс можно вводить команды для cmd `StdIn`, а в нижнем видно `StdOut` и `StrErr`. Думаю, код лучше меня ответит на все вопросы.

Есть незначительные проблемы с кодировкой текста, получаемого от `cmd`, с ходу я не разобрался, но думаю, проблема решаемая, для примера сойдет и так.