# Запуск консольного приложения и взаимодействие

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть у меня .exe,который запускается как консоль[image]

[image: Вот такое]

Возможно ли запустить его и взаимодействовать с ним?(Вводить команды,читать)

Хочу сделать вывод в текстбокс и возможность вводить команды [image: Как-то так]

p.s. ему еще нужны файлы из корня [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А сами пробовали что? Ведь по запросу "C# чтение из консоли" вы по первым ссылкам найдете нужное решение для чтения, и по такому же принципу думаю найдете и отправку команд.

Comment: Пытался запустить просто запуском процесса,но программа писала,шо не может найти файлы

Comment: Ну значит файла, который вы пытаетесь запустить нету, верно? Показываете то, как пытались.

Comment: [Вот пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63541090/12888024), для вашего случая его даже можно упростить.

Comment: @aepot ,правда...я не понял как это использовать 
Я только изучаю c#,прошу не кидать тапками :D

Comment: Вы лучше расскажите, что именно не получается? Добавьте ваш нерабочий код в вопрос.

Comment: [Вот еще пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1086544/373567) из моих старых ответов, правда для WPF, но адаптировать под Winforms не должно быть сложно.