# C# выполнение нескольких команд CMD через один процесс

Tags: c#, cmd

Проблема следующего характера: я использую Desktop-bridge для того, чтобы был можно было вызывать WinAPI методы, но дело в том, что моя программа должна удалять системные файлы, а это возможно только если произошел запуск ПО через администратора. Но desktop-bridge через права администратора можно запустить только в Windows 11. В данной ситуации я решил, что буду использовать CMD.exe. Запускать через администратора и удалять системные файлы командой. Как запустить CMD.exe в проекте единожды, чтобы можно было использовать всего один процесс и выполнять несколько команд? Получается так, что каждый раз, когда мне нужно удалить какой-то системный файл, то приходится запускать новый процесс CMD.exe через права администратора.

Comment: Ну тут вариантов-то немного. Либо генеришь BAT/CMD и скармливаешь его запущенному CMD, а он выполняет нарезанные команды автономно, либо запускаешь CMD, цепляешься за его потоки и рулишь им, словно команды вводишь вручную. И третий вариант, если удалить файл надо не вотпрямщас/срочно-обморочно, а вообще - отложенное удаление, а то и удаление при перезагрузке.

Comment: @Akina благодарю за ответ! А есть ли пример считывать и записывать в потоки?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1086544/373567

Comment: Решил данную проблему путем создания сервера через SignalR. Запускаем сервер с правами администратора и уже он будет заниматься удалением системных файлов =)

Comment: Можно было бы попробовать передавать список файлов параметрами в специально развернутый сервис: `sc start <ServiceName> param1 param2`. Впрочем, сервис Вы уже запустили )