# Есть протенький код, который делает запрос в cmd

Tags: c#

Подскажите, программа запрашивает трассировку в cmd, вопрос в том, как вывести результат этой команды в Console?

```cs
string command = "tracert 8.8.8.8";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C " + command);
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1086544/373567

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример

```
 using (Process process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "ipconfig.exe";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.Start();

            // Synchronously read the standard output of the spawned process.
            StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;
            string output = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // Write the redirected output to this application's window.
            Console.WriteLine(output);

            process.WaitForExit();
        }
```