# Как можно управлять консоль через код

Tags: c#, консоль

Как можно управлять командами в консоли? То есть, перейти в другой репозиторий, написать команду(например shutdown) или что то еще?

Искал в интернете, везде было, что то по типу Console.WriteLine(), а я хочу пользоваться полным функционалом через c#

Comment: Опишите зачем вам это надо, какую задачу решаете?

Comment: Я думал сделать консольное приложение, которое сможет упростить работу с консолью.
 Пример: выключить через 10 минут ('shutdown /s /t 600')

Comment: Если вам нужны "шорткаты" для определенных задач, то делайте себе [CLI утилиты](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools), тогда даже консоль не нужна будет. Например мне частно в папке нужно переименовать все файлы с `длинное имя.mkv` в простое `1.mkv`, кучу файлов руками постоянно такое себе, сделал утилиту, которая просто берет список файлов и циклом переименовывает, теперь я просто в адресной строке нужной мне папки пишу `numname` (короткое имя моей утилиты) и все переименовывается как мне надо. Написать можете в любом месте системы (консоль, путь) этот шорткат.

Comment: А зачем? Вот вам [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1086544/373567), вот вам [два](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63541090/12888024), изучайте. А так для команд консоль не нужна `Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown") { Arguments = "/s /t 600" });`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ оффтоп, Total Commander имеет очень крутой встроенный групповой ренеймер. Если не пользоваться, то идей оттуда можно подобрать.

Comment: @aepot как оффтоп, я уже лет 10+ юзаю linqpad с отдельной репой скриптов для работы с БД, файловой системой, парсеров, обработки изображений, алгоритмов, даже просто ответов на SO. Пишешь скрипт один раз и хочешь через linqpd запускаешь,  хочешь - через консоль, для меня это самая удобная тулза из всех. Сначала юзал бесплатную версию, потом купил платную.

Comment: Пользуюсь ринеймером из тотала. Реально удобнее групового ринеймера не видел) Ни разу не было такого что бы что-то не получилось сделать