# Пассивное чтение консоли(Win forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Открывается консоль с командой `ping ...`. Через несколько секунд(При завершении) в resultText приходит нужный результат. **Полный результат.** Как можно сделать так, чтобы при каждом новом появлении строки переменная `resultat` менялась?

P.s В частности нужно для `ping ... -t`. Там совсем ничего не выводится по понятным причинам.

```
        private void OpenProcces() // Открытие консоли
        {
            resultat = "";
            PSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            PSI.UseShellExecute = false;
            PSI.CreateNoWindow = true;
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = PSI;
            proc.Start();
            var stream = proc.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(866))) // Чтение
            {
                resultat = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(resultat);
                if (InvokeRequired)
                {
                    Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                    {
                        UpdateResultat(resultat);
                    }
                    ));
                }
                else
                    UpdateResultat(resultat);      
            }
        }

        void UpdateResultat(string res) => resultText.Text = res; // Текст в потоке

        private void buttonActivate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resultText.Text = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < buttonsInScene.buttons.Count; i++)
            {
                if (totalAction == buttonsInScene.buttons[i].name)
                {
                    if (buttonsInScene.buttons[i].command == "cmd")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            PSI = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", $@"/c {buttonsInScene.buttons[i].action} {textBoxInfo.Text}"); // Создание процесса

                            Thread thread1 = new Thread(OpenProcces); // Создание потока
                            thread1.Start();
                        }
                        catch (Exception objException)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(objException.Message);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Почему "пассивное"? Странное обозначение) Также "по понятным причинам" - не пойму каким "понятным", то, что команда постоянно выполняется, или что? Ваша сейчас проблема в том, что вы раз получили, и забили, когда как должны бесконечно, в бесконечном цикле крутить чтение потока, пока тот не завершит вывод, что-то вроде [этого](https://pastebin.com/kkHVHdEi) у вас должно быть (кодировку, асинхронность сами сделаете). И да, если вы пинг делаете, то зачем вам консоль? Пингуйте сразу через C# инструментарий и выводите результат.

Comment: 1) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1086544/373567 2) зачем для этого использовать консоль? https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за пример. Он мне помог

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов - запускать ping с параметром -n 1 (количество попыток) нужное количество раз. :-)

Вот работающий пример (который решает задачу, а не показывает образцовый код):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace NsReferences {
    class References {
        static ProcessStartInfo PSI;
        static void OpenProcces() {
            PSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            PSI.UseShellExecute = false;
            PSI.CreateNoWindow = true;
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = PSI;
            proc.Start();
            var stream = proc.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
            string line;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(866))) {
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
        static void Main() {
            try {
                PSI = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c ping 192.168.1.1");
                Thread thread1 = new Thread(OpenProcces);
                thread1.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception objException) { Console.WriteLine(objException.Message); }
        }
    }
}
```

Главная загвоздка - нужно читать не весь вывод до конца, а построчно.