# Как скопировать вывод консоли в программе на C#?

Tags: c#, консоль, компилятор

Как скопировать вывод консоли в программе на C#?
Я хочу создать компилятор на WinForm. Моя программа запускает код (консольную программу file.exe) и мне необходимо получить вывод file.exe (сохранить в текстовый файл/перенаправить в консоль основного приложения и уже там скопировать/другие способы). Вывод программы file.exe я буду использовать как переменную  в моей основной программе, которая запускает file.exe.

Сам код:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
   // код программы file.exe
     string code = "using System; " +
         " namespace test " +
         "{" +
         " public class Programm" +
         "{ " +
         "static void Main(string[] args) " +
         "{" +
         "Console.Write(88); " +
         "Console.ReadKey();" +
         "}} } ";
    // создаю компилятор
     CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "CompilerVerison", "v4.0"} }); 
     CompilerParameters  parameters = new CompilerParameters(new string[] {"mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll"}, "file.exe", true);
     parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
     CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);

     if (results.Errors.HasErrors) 
     //проверяю, есть ли в коде ошибки (переменная code)
     {
         foreach(CompilerError error in results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>()) {
             statusBox.Text += $"Line{error.Line}: {error.ErrorText}";
         }
     }
     else
     {
         statusBox.Text = "---Finished-\n";
       // запускаю программу file.exe, и из консоли этой программы мне нужно получить вывод
           Process.Start($"{Application.StartupPath}/{"file.exe"}"); 
     
     }
 }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1086544/373567

Comment: просто используйте перенаправление вывода из процесса в ваш выходной стрим https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output#answer-4291965