Вывод динамических данных из консоли в C#
К примеру, есть некая программа, которая работает через cmd.exe
После её запуска, в cmd.exe отображается cчётчик с прогрессом выполнения задания.
Вопрос, можно ли этот счётчик как-то динамически-связно отображать в win forms в c# ?

Возможно всё, но решение очень сильно будет зависеть от контекста. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1086544/373567

Контекст простой, выводить  сразу то что показывается в cmd.exe в форме c#

Это не контекст, а задача. Контекст, это что за консольное приложение, ваше или нет, всмысле можете менять его код или нет. Каким образом оно выводит данные в консоль, через стандартный вывод или через буфер, использует ли оно VT100 управляющие коды или нет, и ещё десяток подобных вопросов, от которых будет зависеть решение. Но у вас даже в вопросе одна задача выводить какой-то счётчик, а в комментарии другая - выводить всё. Вопрос слишком абстрактный, чтобы на него ответить. Попробуйте событие OutputDataReceived, ссылка на пример выше.

OutputDataReceived - посмотрел, можно. Теперь вопрос, именно об обновлении "в реальном времени". Я так понял нужно будет создать таймер которых Х секунд будет парсить вывод из cmd.exe ?

Событие будет срабатывать каждый раз когда дочерний процесс что-то в консоль пишет, при любых изменениях в консоли. Никаких таймеров не надо.

А если нужно только цифры, я так понять нужно применить regex на выводе в win forms  ? Потому как в cmd.exe выводится так: processing :  24%  (если без таймера, тогда отлично)

Вы сначала добейтесь хотя-бы вывода текста, вырезать из него число это совсем не проблема.

Вывод динамический удалось сделать, т.е в форме (richbox/label) показывает реалтайм ход событий счётчика, теперь осталось, спарсить значения которые он показывает. Оказывается не просто, потому что данные подгружаются динамически т.е сначала загружается текст, потом счетчики, потом всё запускается и вот только после запуска (старта счётчика) - нужно начинать парсинг параматров.

Ну регуляркой ловите \d+%, если есть, выводите. Если нет, пропускайте строку.

Я так и зделал только не строку а поставил i++ посчитал после какого номера начинается показ результатов, типа i == 7 начинаем парсинг

Это уж как вам удобнее, но я бы на содержимое реагировал, а не строки считал. А то захочет разработчик убрать или добавить строчку в вывод в будущей версии приложения, и у вас всё сломается. Чем меньше условий надо выполнить для успешной интеграции, тем лучше.

Дело в том что ещё в таком варианте оно как бы не сразу всё появляется, даже в моём самом упрощенном с внутренним счётчиком, когда нажал на кнопку и результат выводится не сразу так как он парсится, как бы тоже не очень, но, это единственный как я понял вариант вывести его в форму.

Вопрос, относительно "софта-обвертки" - его можно где-то разместить, чтобы люди могли скачать его и использовать (бесплатно) ? Или сейчас такое уже не "модно" ?

Не понимаю вопроса. Десктопные приложения можно публиковать в Microsoft Store. Для этого потребуется сертификат разработчика, которым потребуется подписать приложения.
